# Designing a drawing class hierarchy in iOS

Tags: iphone

My end goal is to draw a report that looks like MS Word using Quartz into a UIView, having and then having that UIView in a UIScrollView.

What I have now is a top level Report Object, and then it's children are parts of the report to draw like ReportTitle, ReportTable, ReportSplitColumn, etc.  The top level Report Object looks like:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIFont *font;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat margins; 
@property (nonatomic, assign) TextObjectStyle style;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGColorRef color;

- (CGSize)size;
```

In my proof of concept, I created a ReportView object that knows how to draw ReportObjects that take a specific ReportObject, and draws it at a specific point.  So my drawRect would like something like:

```
//pseudocode
drawRect: {
  //get the current context
  CGFloat startHeight = 0;
  CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0, startHeight);
  startHeight += [self drawReportTitle:currentContext atPoint:CGPointMake(0, point.y)].height;
  point.y = startHeight;

  startHeight += [self drawParagraph:currentContext withText:paragraphs atPoint:CGPointMake(0, point.y)].height;
  point.y = startHeight;

}
```

What I started trying to do was have my ReportView have a property of `NSArray *ReportObjectsArray` and then have my caller class set that value, and then have my ReportView draw it.  I was hoping I could do something like:

```
for (ReportView *r in self.ReportObjectsArray) {
  startHeight += [self drawReportObject].height atPoint:CGPointMake(0, point.y;
  point.y = startHeight
}
```

Except the problem I realize is, my own classes don't know how to draw themselves.  I think I remember seeing this pattern in a Java book where the class knows how to draw itself.  And that does make sense to me.  However the problem I ran into was in the end, I want one UIView of type ReportView that is scrollable in UIScrollView.  I wasn't really sure if each ReportObject should subclass UIView instead and then add each of these objects to the UIView in the scrollView as a subView, and then have it draw itself that way.  Is that the better way to go?  I'm not really sure.  If it's not, what is my alternative?  Would I have all my classes have a draw method, but in it, it just posts a notification and then in my ReportView class, I can have it listen to those notifications, and then call the appropriate draw methods?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely want to use a hierarchy of `UIView`s rather than implementing a lot `drawRect`s. `UIKit` is  very good about optimization and you defeat that if you do a lot of non-optimzed/naive `drawRect`s.

You might or might not create custom `UIView` subsclasses for all your objects. It may be enough to use the builtin `UIView` subclasses and just create them based on your report objects. Subclassing is more complicated but is generally needed if you need to do more custom layout (in `layoutSubviews`) than the standard struts and springs provide.